# prevent iPad4 from sleeping while music plays - was working in iPad 3 & 2

Tags: ipad, avaudioplayer

I have a music player app for iPad which was first created for iPad 2, then iPad 3 and is now being used on iPad 4's.

It used to work as follows: If the music was playing, the screen would dim but it would not go to sleep. This no longer works on iPad4. Anyone have any ideas on how to make this work for iPad 4? I know I can set "idleTimerDisabled" and maybe set the brightness, but I would prefer the screen to dim on its own.

Any tips or clues would be greatly appreciated.

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (
        kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
        sizeof (sessionCategory),
        &sessionCategory
    );
    AudioSessionSetActive(true);

// setup so app does not lock - screen fades to dark
// ***** iPad must be plugged into a power source ***
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```